# C# Form not catching any mouse event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I have few controls (Label, Custom Textbox, Datagridview) docked on a form. When I tried to hook the MouseMove event to the individual controls, the event fires perfectly fine but when I tried to hook the event on the form itself, the mousemove event do not respond at all. What could be the possible cause of this?

Edit:

Here is the event hook from resources.cs

```
this.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.LogicSimulationViewerForm_MouseMove);
```

and here is the function handled on catching the event

```
private void LogicSimulationViewerForm_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
           //DOESN'T WORK!!!
        }
```

Comment: It only fires when you click the form itself, not its elements.

Comment: I'm talking about mousemove not mousedown

Comment: You should create **minimal** example code that doesn't work and update your question with it. No one will be able to help you without source code.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure why you would need a **minimal** example code for something that is **ridiculously trivial** but I'm not the one to complain so I will edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this is that in difference of `WPF` in `WindowsForms` the event is "blocked" by the control that handled it (in `WPF` the event will be pushed to the parent up to the Visual Tree, or in opposite direction: from parent to child).

So to catch that event you need to process it on application level and do not subscribe to single control event.

For more detailed example how to handle it can look here:

[How do I capture the mouse mouse move event in my winform application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063974/how-do-i-capture-the-mouse-mouse-move-event-in-my-winform-application)

Comment: So is there anyway to circumvent the "block"?

Answer (score 3):

Winforms events don't bubble up like in WPF or in Html. Therefore if the controls are docked on the form, the form doesn't expose any surface of it's own and it doesn't catch any mouse events. However 'under water', all windows messages (a mouse move is a windows message), do pass the form, so it is possible to catch that message.

**edit**
Tigran has [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063974/how-do-i-capture-the-mouse-mouse-move-event-in-my-winform-application) to a good example for the use of IMessageFilter  that makes creating another example a bit superfluous :)

Comment: How can I handle the message then?