# C# Mouse Movement Outside Form

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse

I am trying to track mouse movements in my code. It's easy to track mouse movements in form window but i wanted to track mouse movements outside of my from window. i mean i will **minimize my from to tray and track where it is**. Any idea how to track mouse movemtns outside of my form windows with sample codes or sample explanation links? I am using c# and i would like to know how. Thanks for your help.

For form windows i tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063974/how-do-i-capture-the-mouse-move-event-in-my-winform-application) and it works perfectly.

What i want.

I want to get to know when user move mouse left to right or right to left and show message about warning.

I want my application as a service (actually its not so neccessary if you can help on form application it will be fair enough too) and startup with os. and **track mouse movements and catch if user move his/her mouse left to right or right to left**. Thats it. I hope this edit will be very specific explanation.

Comment: you could make a form which fills the page, and then you set the visible to false

Comment: What information do you want to get relating to the cursor position ? The handle of the window underneath it ? The process name owning the window over which the cursor is, etc. ?

Comment: You can only get a good answer when you describe *exactly* why you need this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this properly, I think you will need to use global hooks. [This](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/) seems nice and is C# managed code.

Comment: thanks for the link Francis. Thats what i was looking for, it works perfectly.