# Trigger MouseMove/MouseUp After Leaving ListView

Tags: c#, listview, events, mousemove

I have an application with a `ListView` control that contains a number of objects the user can "drag and drop" within a `Panel`. Originally, I used `DoDragDrop` but decided not to so that I could implement a semi-transparent, custom control I call `ShadowBox`. The `ShadowBox` inherits from `Form` and is centred on the mouse cursor as you place the item. The item is placed in the `Panel` as a custom control that inherits from `Label` we can call `Item`.

When using the the `MouseMove` event on the `Item` I am able to freely drag the `ShadowBox` anywhere on screen and it disappears once I let go of the mouse regardless of where on the screen I am. This means `MouseMove` is continuing to fire even after the cursor technically left the bounds of the `Item`.

My problem has two elements:

1) When I do the same thing on a `ListView` the `MouseMove` is not fired unless the mouse is directly over the `ListView`. This means the `ShadowBox` blocks the `MouseMove` from triggering and I can't continue the `MouseMove` as I enter the panel. Is there a way to fix this (see code below). I think that this:

[How do I capture the mouse move event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063974/how-do-i-capture-the-mouse-move-event)

may be my answer, but I can't get it to work.

2) Just for the sake of my understanding, and assuming I'm not just doing something wrong on my `MouseDown` or `MouseMove` events, why is the `MouseMove` behaviour different for `Item` than for `ListView`? (i.e. why does `MouseMove` seem to continue to fire even when the mouse isn't directly over the `Item`, but the same is not true for the `ListView`?)

```
ShadowBox sb;   
Point startMousePosition;

private void Toolbox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvi;
    Point p;

    lvi = lvToolbox.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
    if (lvi != null)
    {
        if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            sb = new ShadowBox();

            p = lvToolbox.PointToScreen(e.Location);
            sb.Show();
            sb.Size = new Size(144, 108); //Note: I simplified this code, the size will depend on the ListViewItem selected.
            sb.Opacity = 0.8;
            sb.Location = new Point(p.X - sb.Width / 2, p.Y - sb.Height / 2);
            sb.Show();
            startMouseDown = new Point(sb.Width / 2, sb.Height / 2); //e.Location;

            lvToolbox.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Toolbox_MouseMove);
        }
    }
}

private void Toolbox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
   {
       sb.Location = PointToScreen(new Point(e.X - startMouseDown.X, e.Y - startMouseDown.Y));
   }
}

private void Toolbox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (sb != null)
    {
        sb.Dispose();
    }

    lvToolbox.MouseMove -= new MouseEventHandler(Toolbox_MouseMove);
}
```

Comment: Mouse capture is the key here.  If you don't want ListView to capture the mouse then use `e.Handled = true;`.  And `sb.Capture = true;` to get the  MouseMove event to fire on your ShadowBox class.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Where do I place e.Handled = true;? It gives an error ("'MouseEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Handled'") in my MouseDown and MouseMove event methods.

Comment: Oh, right, just sb.Capture is enough.  Keep in mind that you now need to use the ShadowBox.MouseMove and MouseUp events.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. For some reason, moving the mouse too quickly caused me to leave the ShadowBox and stop the MouseMove from triggering, but I fixed that by adding a MouseLeave event that recentred the ShadowBox. I'd up-vote your comment, but I don't have sufficient privileges :)