# Tell if a user has interacted with the keyboard or mouse at all (C#)?

Tags: c#, boolean, mouseevent, keypress, mouselistener

Right now I am trying to figure out how to tell if a user has interacted with a certain program at all (mouse clicks, mouse movement, keyboard presses, etc.). What will happen is if there is user interaction, the method would set a global variable to true. I don't have any code, since I am not sure where to go with this at the moment.

Comment: Are you using windows forms? Is this "certain program" your program, or just any program?

Comment: Just a small windows forms application, I want to know (while it is being used) if a user has used the keyboard or mouse at all.

Comment: this may be hard to implement for your first time. but give it a try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063974/how-do-i-capture-the-mouse-move-event

Comment: @LibertyLocked  I will give that one a look, did not see that come up when I was looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary unfortunately, don't think I can implement that.

Comment: there is also one for keyboard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application