# [.net]is there any mouse movement event in forms?

Tags: c#, .net, mouse

is there any event in .net forms to find the movement of the mouse? and if there isn't, please suggest me good input library. if you could help me it's going to be very nice :P

Comment: You could google this :(

Comment: I know but I can't find. that's why I'm posting here

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063974/how-do-i-capture-the-mouse-move-event and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/mouse-events-in-windows-forms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I capture the mouse move event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063974/how-do-i-capture-the-mouse-move-event)

Answer (score 1):

```
// The following example displays the location of the form in screen coordinates
// on the caption bar of the form.
private void Form1_Move(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = "Form screen position = " + this.Location.ToString();
}
```

For that please read [Control.Move Event on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.move(v=vs.110).aspx) or stackoverflow.

[MouseMove Event in Form on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2064009/3090544)