# I want to create a WinUI application which can perform actions on some mouse gesture

Tags: wpf, windows, uwp, winui-3

Here is what I want to achieve:

- I want to create a Windows app that listens in the background for mouse-wiggling gestures while selecting the file. Based on that, I want to show a popup where users can drag their files.

Is it possible to use Windows APIs? Or is it just not possible? I have seen an app for Mac that can do that: https://dropoverapp.com/.

I am not that much of an expert in building Windows apps, but if you are a person who knows this, it would be a real help. I wanted to learn Windows development, and I am really excited to build this app. I know it's futile to build something complicated, but please, if you can help me, it would be really helpful for me.

Comment: Doing simple drag & drag is relatively easy  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/drag-and-drop) but doing what's in the link is much more complicated, if ever possible, especially if you don't know Windows that much.

Comment: Perhaps you can start from capturing global mouse movement. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2064009/3137337 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/toub/low-level-mouse-hook-in-c